# Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0

Tags: android, permissions

My application works normally on my test device (When I install it via ADT & when I install it via the exported APK file) but it fails on Play Store testing device with the following error:

> Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0, this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

I'm new in Android world and I don't understand why it works on my device & it fails on the same device at Play Store test?

What this error type means in Android work environment?

I added the following permission

> android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

in AndroidManifest.xml as recommended here: [Permission Denial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179159/permission-denial-startactivity-asks-to-run-as-user-2-but-is-calling-from-user)

But the application failed again to launch / open on their test device.

**EDIT:**

**Test device running Android 4.3**

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who had this issue, for me it was simply a case of having an activity with the wrong name in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

I didn't need to add any permissions, once the activity name was corrected (in mine it stated the wrong package name), it ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while trying to use move Files using the version of the application that I plan to post to market.  The problem was that the files I was trying to move were created during the application development process by the app that was signed with the debug certificate.  So I was trying to access a file created with one certificate with an app that was signed by another certificate.  I cleaned up all the files and started fresh with new files created by the app I plan to post to market.  Now I am able to access and move the files without the Android System complaining :)

Comment: How did you " I cleaned up all the files and started fresh with new files created by the app"? I'm running into this issue and believe its because I and switching between my macs with two different debug certificates.

Comment: On further testing, the certificate turned out not to be the issue.  I was only able to write to the SD Card's Android/data/com.your_app/files folder.  The other directories on the SD card are read-only.  I know that file explorer apps can write to any directory on the SD card, so they are using some undocumented trick to gain write access.

Answer (score -4):

please try a rooted phone. this error is caused by users permissions
root=uid0
you=uid -1 or -2

Comment: Bad way. Will you send instructions to make phone rooted to users?