# Cordova security exception android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a mobile app with cordova/phonegap and I've installed OAuth plugin. When I try to use this plugin(that try to open a popup to authenticate on twitter) my console show me:

```
E/DatabaseUtils(2355): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the permission mentioned in the error message into your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
```

Edit: If you have trouble adding this permission please refer to the following:

[Permission Denial: this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full)

Comment: Are you getting a different error message this time or the same?