# Listfragment stops updating after some hours

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listfragment

I'm having this really annoying and strange issue with a ListFragment. The Listfragment works fine at first - updates without any issue even when closing the app and what not.
Then after maybe 12 hours, it stops updating.

I have a background thread that collects data and inserts it into an SQLite database and then sends the same data to a server. The server receives the data and I can see that the data is inserted into the SQLite database.
The ListFragment then should display this data that is in the SQLite database, but it won't show data that has just been inserted into the SQLite database.

Here's the exception is get from the console.

[image]

Here's the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fo.vera.kontakt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="controller.SignInActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="controller.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="controller.ActivitiesListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="taskclasses.BluetoothService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone know what this might be?

Comment: It seems a problem with permission. How are you creating the db? Are you using a "public" (visible to other apps) db?

Comment: I can't seem to find any explicit statement that states if it is public or private. All I can see is that I create the DBHelper like this:

DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(context);

(DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper)

And I open the db like this:

SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Are you using uid in your manifest or some settings about the uid?

Comment: No, I've added the manifest to the problem description.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full Maybe there is some problem if your app uses or requires root access (from the image I see uid = 0 i.e. root access)

Comment: You should add an `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` permission as you can see in the log.