# Android Requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Tags: android

I'm trying to access website through simple HttpClient and its throwing error as below/ I have tried to   put this in android manifest  **android.permission.INTERNET** but still it's throwing same error

```
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-25 19:10:05.380  12689-12710/? E/Launcher.BadgeCache,﹕ Do not updateBadgeCounts!!, multiple data for appIndex=1
04-25 19:10:09.875    2346-2744/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
            at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
            at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 19:10:10.405    2749-2749/com.example.innovator.httpclientapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.innovator.httpclientapp/com.example.innovator.httpclientapp.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at com.example.innovator.httpclientapp.MyHttpClient.getWebsiteResult(MyHttpClient.java:42)
            at com.example.innovator.httpclientapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
```

Below is my onCreateMethod

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // here instantiate a java class for retrieving the https url result
    MyHttpClient client =  new MyHttpClient();

    // read the input stream
    TextView textView =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    // setting the output to text view
    textView.setText(client.getWebsiteResult());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full).

> android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL is a signature level
>   permission. Your app will not be able to use it until and unless it
>   has the same signature as the system.
>
> Which is not something you can achieve unless you either are the
>   creator or the system build, or collaborating with them such that they
>   are willing to sign your apk with their certificate. In other words,
>   this is off limits for most developers.

However, reading your loagcat and code.

```
04-25 19:10:10.405    2749-2749/com.example.innovator.httpclientapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.innovator.httpclientapp/com.example.innovator.httpclientapp.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Above error suggests that a network call cannot be made on main thread. So, make a new thread and start network call from that thread. It might solve your problem.

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    // your network call
  }
}.start();
```

If you want to have callbacks and stuff you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as well.

Also a suggestion, for making nice and quick network calls you can use [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). It is my personal favorite and very easy to use!

Comment: Its working after keeping in thread...Earlier its stopping at httpclient.execute(httpget);