# User asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0 error

Tags: android-studio, android-permissions, android-internet

First of all, PLEASE don't take it as a duplicate!

I have tried every single thing I have found over stackoverflow and other sources but nothing seems to work for me!

I have exported my project from Eclipse and imported it in AS and got this error.
 I have tried to create a test project in AS and got the exact same error for a basic project that tries to make a php-request, nothing else!

Please note: The project from eclipse work perfectly ,tested in a bunch of phones, while the exact same project will give me the following error without any line of code changed!
 Please note 2: Don't bother giving me links to documentation, I have read my eyes out in the past week and nothing seems to be working at all!

```
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346): Writing exception to parcel
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
06-27 16:05:37.060: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Ain't this the same problem you had here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364076/android-frustrating-network-error

Comment: This is the actual error...but yea...Although the first topic was too spammed already