# Facing android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL when trying to open JSON File from Phone memory

Tags: android, json, file, exception

I need your help, I am facing below mentioned issue in Android App, Overall scenario is, we are downloading a JSON file from server, which having JSONObject data and save at some location in Android Phone, in debug mode we are taking data from this JSON file which is working fine, and from signed apk it is also working fine, but when we download app from google play store, we are unable to take data from this file and instead of that I am facing below mentioned issue.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15169)
at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2492)
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Kindly help me out in this.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full)

Comment: @Sanoop: which answer you want to refer on this page, I have checked their this issue is coming only in Samsung S4 Mini Device where it is working fine Micromax Android One, Samsung J2, Moto G2