# Android SMS & GPS App - Security Permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-gps

I'm having issues with my prototype application. It works fine between two emulators on my PC, but when I install it on my phone it won't send text messages or even care to ask for the permission (if that is the issue).
Furthermore, I'm recieving the same error no matter what I do, on app start, each time I press a button and on every new intent start:

```
 E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
                                                at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
                                                at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
                                                at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I've been looking at a lot of similar issues, and I did add

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

to my manifest, but nothing seems to work for me.
The real odd thing to me is that the error occurs on application start, because nothing interesting really seems like nothing interesting is happening at that point:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

// Go to contact list
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i  = new Intent(this,AddContact.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void onGPS(View view) {
    Intent j = new Intent(this,GPSActivity.class);
    startActivity(j);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you by any chance installed the app for multiple users on the same device?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full)

Comment: Hm OK, so it seems to be an S3 issue. Which is actually the phone I'm using! - No I did not install the app for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is seemingly with Samsung Galaxy S3. The link: [Permission Denial: this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full)
Provided by Sumighosh  Chaurvil explains the problem; And that there's really not much to do about it.

I installed the application on another phone, and it works with no problems whatsoever!