# Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user?

Tags: android, mysql, linux, sqlite

I want to get a row by an id from sqlite database but every time the app crashes and it gives this error and I searched the internet the result is that set the user manually as (user 0), but I don't know how to do that could you help me with that.

Query code:

```
 String[] clumns = {KEY_ID,KEY_ENG, KEY_KURD, KEY_KURD2, KEY_AR, KEY_AR2, KEY_AME,KEY_BRE,KEY_Fav};
        Cursor cursor15 = myDataBase.query(table, clumns, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor15 != null) {
            cursor15.moveToFirst();
            Item itemmm = new Item();
            itemmm.setEng(cursor15.getString(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_ENG)));
            itemmm.setKurd(cursor15.getString(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_KURD)));
            itemmm.setKurd2(cursor15.getString(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_KURD2)));
            itemmm.setAr(cursor15.getString(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_AR)));
            itemmm.setAr2(cursor15.getString(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_AR2)));
            itemmm.setAme(cursor15.getString(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_AME)));
            itemmm.setBre(cursor15.getString(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_BRE)));
            itemmm.setFav(cursor15.getInt(cursor15.getColumnIndex(KEY_Fav)));
            return itemmm;
```

Logcat

```
12-08 19:12:45.132 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:12:45.353 840-2201/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                               java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15169)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2492)
                                                   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-08 19:12:45.373 840-840/? E/PersonaManagerService: returning null in  getPersonasForUser
12-08 19:12:45.403 196-293/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:45.413 196-293/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:45.413 196-12449/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:45.413 196-12449/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:45.473 196-293/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:45.483 196-293/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:46.194 196-301/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:46.194 196-301/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:48.126 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:12:48.546 1814-1814/? E/GestureService: updateFlags started
12-08 19:12:48.546 1814-1814/? E/GestureService: bVertical = false
12-08 19:12:48.546 1814-1814/? E/GestureService: bHorizontal = false
12-08 19:12:48.546 1814-1814/? E/GestureService: bHorizontalWave = false
12-08 19:12:49.317 840-2199/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                               java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15169)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2492)
                                                   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-08 19:12:49.828 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:49.838 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:49.848 3691-3706/? E/Samsung TTS: onIsLanguageAvailable() - lang : eng, country : USA, variant : , iResult : 1
12-08 19:12:49.868 196-1531/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:49.868 196-1531/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:51.009 196-293/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:51.019 196-293/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:12:51.129 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:12:51.159 840-1377/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1758
12-08 19:12:54.132 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:12:57.135 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:00.139 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:03.142 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:06.145 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:09.148 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:12.141 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:15.145 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:18.148 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:19.429 840-1016/? E/MISC PowerHAL: sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or directory
12-08 19:13:19.429 840-1016/? E/MISC PowerHAL: sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input10/enabled: No such file or directory
12-08 19:13:19.679 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:19.679 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:19.910 840-1014/? E/lights: write_int failed to open -1
12-08 19:13:20.340 13431-13431/? E/videowall-TranscodeReceiver: broadcastMSG : android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
12-08 19:13:21.141 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:21.151 840-1377/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1759
12-08 19:13:24.144 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:24.464 840-1068/? E/PersonaManagerService: returning null in  getPersonasForUser
12-08 19:13:24.474 1092-1092/? E/KeyguardHostView: KeyguardHostView()
12-08 19:13:25.846 1092-1092/? E/LSO: LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
12-08 19:13:26.256 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:26.256 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:26.366 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:26.366 196-16581/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:26.407 196-301/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:26.407 196-301/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

12-08 19:13:27.157 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:30.151 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:33.154 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON

                                    [ 12-08 19:13:33.154   840:  990 D/         ]
                                    TIMA: QCOM_send_command result--0


                                    [ 12-08 19:13:33.154   840:  990 D/         ]
                                    TIMA_PKM_measure_kernel returns with resp..ret=512!


                                    [ 12-08 19:13:33.154   840:  990 D/         ]
                                    TAL: TIMA_PKM_measure_kernel--int8_t TIMA_PKM_measure_kernel(TIMA_handle_t, void*, uint32_t, void*, uint32_t, uint32_t)


                                    [ 12-08 19:13:33.154   840:  990 D/         ]
                                    TIMA: QCOM_send_command--int8_t QCOM_send_command(TIMA_handle_t, void*, uint32_t, void*, uint32_t, uint32_t)


                                    [ 12-08 19:13:33.154   840:  990 D/         ]
                                    rsp_len = 1008 rcvd_data_len = 1040, self_calculate_len=1040
12-08 19:13:36.157 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:39.150 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:40.151 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: duration time is -3 ==> not Live but Static thumbnail
12-08 19:13:40.311 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:40.462 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:40.592 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:40.742 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:40.902 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:41.062 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:41.222 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:41.443 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:41.643 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:41.823 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:41.993 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:42.153 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:42.163 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:42.334 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:42.534 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:42.724 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:42.914 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:43.154 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:43.345 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:43.545 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:43.735 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:43.995 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:44.206 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:44.406 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:44.606 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:44.816 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:45.016 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:45.157 187-187/? E/SMD: DCD ON
12-08 19:13:45.227 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:45.447 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:45.627 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:45.807 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:45.967 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:46.138 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:46.288 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:46.508 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:46.848 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:47.039 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
12-08 19:13:47.259 13431-2224/? E/videowall-TranscodeService: End Transcoding for List !!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission Denial: this requires android.permission.INTERACT\_ACROSS\_USERS\_FULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full)

Comment: It's not a duplicate this post and read the other post