# ListView - Unrelated security exception on addFooterView() method

Tags: android, listview, securityexception

Im trying to add a footer view for a `ListView` in Android and i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview) answer however no matter what I try the moment i add the line:

```
poiLv.addFooterView(loadMore);
```

the activity fails with a security exception:

```
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14610)
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2258)
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:663)
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
09-22 17:21:53.761: E/DatabaseUtils(3029):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I tried adding the footer before, after the `setAdapter()` or without adapter at all but it made no difference. I tried different layout formats including: Button, TextView, EditText but unsuccessfully. Has anyone faced similar issues with footer view?

Im testing on a Samsung S4 device, Android 4.4.2

Comment: This exception doesn't look like it has anything to do with addFooterView.

Comment: yeah seems the same to me. but everytime i add that single line of code thats what happens

Comment: Did you test it on the emulator as well ?

Comment: @2Dee i didnt yet, but i can give it a try

Comment: addFooterView probably isn't relevant here... it's just a trigger to some other project configuration problem. One of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267368/permission-denial-get-set-setting-for-user-asks-to-run-as-user-2-but-is-callin suggest a problem in the manifest.

Comment: and don't forget to clean and rebuild.. :)

Comment: @Raanan ive already checked that answer but i didnt find anything relevant for my case. and of course ive already gone through clean/rebuild/restart

Comment: Just making sure, sometime when you're stuck on these annoying things you forget to cover your "Voodoo" solutions.

Comment: @Raanan of course that happens more frequently then id like to :D and thanks for your time