# Android Permission issue with purchasing flow

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

When i try purchase item

```
try {

 Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", "test");

 PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

 startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
 new   Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));


 }catch (RemoteException e){


  }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException se){

  }
```

I got following error:

> Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Does anyone know what is the issue related to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this link should give permission in manifest.

> [Permission Denial: startActivity asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179159/permission-denial-startactivity-asks-to-run-as-user-2-but-is-calling-from-user)

Comment: i added following to Manifest
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>