# Android Crash on Android 8.0 Oreo: SecurityException: Permission Denial: null asks to run as user 450 but is calling from user 0

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I upgrade my phone to Android Oreo. When I'm running my app on this device. My app crashes. While it's running well on Android 7 and lower devices.

This is the log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: com.test.test, PID: 28271
                                                         java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: null asks to run as user 450 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
                                                             at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.addClient(IAutoFillManager.java:326)
                                                             at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:896)
                                                             at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewExited(AutofillManager.java:487)
                                                             at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded(View.java:6945)
                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:17413)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1658)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: That looks a lot like [what was asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45842943/115145). How are you causing this crash?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have experienced this problem.

In my case, after perform a `startActivity`, the application throwed the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: null asks to run as user 66853 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
       at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.addClient(IAutoFillManager.java:326)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:896)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewExited(AutofillManager.java:487)
       at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded(View.java:6945)
       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:17413)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3326)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4955)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4746)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4686)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:711)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7877)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7835)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7823)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1565)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3025)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1308)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:350)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

After hours of investigation, I identified that my class `BaseActivity`, who is extended by all application activities, has implemented a protected method called `getUserId`, like the example below:

```
 class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ...

   protected int getUserId() {
     return getCurrentUserRepository().getId();
   }
 }
```

I just changed the method name to another and the application back to work again:

```
 class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ...

   protected int getApplicationUserId() {
     return getCurrentUserRepository().getId();
   }
 }
```

I could not find any method with same name in base classes, but as can we see in stacktrace, this method was probably called by **Reflection**.

**Other important think** is that just activities who implements any `EditText` view throws the exception. The problem occour after implementation of [Autofill Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html) in **API 26**.

Comment: I had the same issue, had a method called getUserId, I renamed it to getUserID and then i worked - unbelievable

Comment: Working for me too after change getUserId() method name.

Comment: Same issue here. Renamed method name and now it works

Comment: i cant import or find the  getCurrentUserRepository() class name in android studio @KasperFinneNielsen

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced same issue in kotlin. This Issue Happens only when Edittext is implemented in activity and Having getUserId() method in this Class or it parent class. Changing  **getUserId()** to **getUserIdd()** fixed my problem.

In Kotlin I had a variable

```
var userId=0
```

I changed it to

```
var userIdd=0
```

Solved My problem.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064389/1147688) answer, and looking at the sources of [UserHandle.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/UserHandle.java) we see the meaning of the framework user id's.

```
# | @UserIdInt            | Value  | Status     | Description |
# | --------------------- | ------ | ---------- | ------------| 
# | USER_OWNER            | 0      | deprecated | "owner" user of the device
# | USER_SYSTEM           | 0      | ok         | "system" user of the device
# | USER_ALL              | -1     | ok         | ALL users on the device
  | USER_CURRENT          | -2     | ok         | the currently active user
# | USER_CURRENT_OR_SELF  | -3     | ok         | id from which we would like to send to the current user
# | USER_NULL             | -10000 | ok         | An undefined user id
```

Then to understand what `android:protectionLevel="signature"` means, you'll have to read the page about [permission-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html). Which is summarized in the table:

[image]

So what you need to do in your `AndroidManifest.xml` depend a lot on what API's you need to support, as higher > 23 API's also require a `android:permissionGroup=` [definition](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups), for non-normal ("dangerous") permissions...

To be able to hold **INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS**, your app has to be signed by the firmware's signing key or it has to be installed on the system partition.

To be able to hold **INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL**, your app has to be signed by the firmware's signing key.

**Therefore finally add this in your manifest file:**

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: The crash only happens on Android 8.0. I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: @weiwang try to change method getUserId() to getUserID()