# Android - java.lang.SecurityException in android.os.Parcel.readException

Tags: android, geolocation, securityexception, android-securityexception

I have been working on location based Android application.Also I have taken care of run time dangerous location permissions. It works great while testing the various devices from 4.0 to 8.0.

I have no other dangerous permissions.

If the exception is for the run time location permission, it would have read something like below

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
```

But instead, the logs are as below.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1683)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1636)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zzb (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdx.zza (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcea.zza (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzceh.zza (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.location.zzi.zzb (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd.zzb (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb.zza (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzb (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.zzaik (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.onConnected (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.onConnected (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzakf (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzv (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzakg (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Number of count for the exception is 1216 over the google play console & impacted users are 368 within short period of time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: "Also I have taken care of run time dangerous location permissions" -- perhaps you have flaws in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for the comment. I will verify the implementation again twice. I have another question. Can the possible reason be different than the flaws in my implementation?

Comment: I cannot rule it out, but I cannot think of a scenario to explain it, other than you not holding the permission at the time of making your Play Services SDK call.

Comment: I have the same issue in one of our apps. Funnily enough this error only (not 100% sure but it appears to) appears on devices running Android 8.0

Comment: Update: Mostly occurs on Android 8.0, but we have at least 3 happening on Android 7.0 (Our 8.0 and 7.0 userbases are equal in size). I found another person with a similar issue, in that case it happened because they had a function called getUserId() in their app. (It was being accessed through reflection) Turns out I also have one that's called that, in a file with unused code. Maybe you also have this function and it's causing issues? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845912/android-crash-on-android-8-0-oreo-securityexception-permission-denial-null-as