# Showing security exception on Samsung Galaxt S9 (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-securityexception

My app runs on all other devices except Samsung Galaxy S9 (Oreo).

That is the only phone I have with oreo. All other phones it is working fine (Moto g4 plus, Samsung A8, Samsung galaxy S7, and many other).

Was any new security feature added in oreo?

I couldn't spot out it. Anyone knows?

Log below

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
   at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1958)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1904)
   at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.addClient (IAutoFillManager.java:326)
   at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked (AutofillManager.java:896)
   at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewExited (AutofillManager.java:487)
   at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded (View.java:7577)
   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:18627)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3527)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3527)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3527)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3527)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3527)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3527)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3527)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2030)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7745)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:658)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845912/android-crash-on-android-8-0-oreo-securityexception-permission-denial-null-as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845912/android-crash-on-android-8-0-oreo-securityexception-permission-denial-null-as) helps me to solve the issue.

I had **getUserId()** method on my Activity. I just renamed to **getUserID()** (as they told in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845912/android-crash-on-android-8-0-oreo-securityexception-permission-denial-null-as) accepted answer).

Previously it was

```
 public int getUserId() {
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    int temp = app_preferences.getInt("UserId", 0);
    return temp;
}
```

Now I changed it to

```
 public int getUserID() {
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    int temp = app_preferences.getInt("UserId", 0);
    return temp;
}
```

Problem solved.. For more details see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845912/android-crash-on-android-8-0-oreo-securityexception-permission-denial-null-as).