# Android Pie - 9 (API 28) : Installing APK .... not successfully installing

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-install-apk, android-9.0-pie

Recently I have **updated** OS to **Android 9(Pie)** and found that Whenever I try to install APK from android studio it does not work.

As it just shows **"Installing Apk..."** and freezes at that point, After waiting too long it shows **"Application Installation Failed"** with **"Installation failed with message null."**

Did anyone else is facing this issue? If yes then help, please.

Here is the attached screenshot.

[image]

Device and Enviornment Details :

**Device : MI A1**

**Android Studio : 3.2.1**

Any Help, Idea, Suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: is device not showing up or apk not installing (if not installing than check min sdk version)

Comment: does your device have multiple user accounts?

Comment: No multiple user account, device is showing up, min sdk version is : 16

Comment: before update 9(Pie). you install this app in your phone ???

Comment: Yes, before the update it was working fine.

Comment: Okay go on Setting->app and check this app uninstall for all user or not. And also try to restart your device and re-install the app @TarunDholakiya

Comment: uninstalled for all user still does not works

Comment: Try to restart your phone and install.

Comment: Android Studio Restart, Device Restart, Build Project, Clean Project, Invalidate caches and Restart nothing works in this case.

Comment: try changing the application id and see if that works

Comment: after attaching device try killing adb server and start it again.

Comment: If anybody have android 9, can you please try on your device with any sample project by doing simple installation from android studio.

Comment: Is there any logcat about instaling?

Comment: I m getting below lines in logcat

12/28 17:32:44: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t D:\Tarun_Workplace\DemosAndExamples\gps-app\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk D:\Tarun_Workplace\DemosAndExamples\gps-app\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Comment: There is too long logcat could not post whole but all lines shows the slice_"number".apk

Comment: @TarunDholakiya do `InvalidateCashes/Restart` in Android studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to fix the problem..

1. Go to settings and turn off your `Developer Options`.
2. Restart your device.
3. Go to settings again and turn on your `Developer Options` back (By hitting the `Build Number` multiple times).

Now you are able to install APKs from your Android Studio as you were earlier. Restarting the device is optional but better do that.