# React native app failed to run on android pie

Tags: android, react-native

My react native app got failed to run on android Pie (`android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`).
But I can run my app on android Oreo Device

What I have already tried, but didn't solve the problem:
1. I have tried deleting node modules, and reinstalling with `npm install`
2. I tried `gradlew clean`
3. Disable google play protect

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from
>   pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this
>   requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28134444/11212074 Please refer.

Comment: i have added that permission in manifest but unfortunately it didnt help me solve the problem

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458482/11212074

Comment: Finally this answer work well for my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993338/5307383